# Construct describing an inherent sense of right/wrong?

Tags: ethics, metaethics

In Christian and especially Protestant philosophy there seems to be an implied notion that humans possess some ability to "sense" moral right and wrong.  When one performs or contemplates an action that is "wrong", one is able to distinguish it as wrong via this extra-sensory perception.  This sense is not considered a thing that is *learned*, it is simply experienced.  Note that this is different than moral relativism in that it posits an objective morality that is merely observed by the individual sensing it.

The in-universe explanation of how this sense functions isn't important for my question.  I am more curious about this concept as a general human phenomenon.

**Is this "sin sense" a cross-cultural phenomenon or is it specific to certain groups?  If so, is there a general construct that describes this "sin sense"?**

Here are some arbitrary quotes that I've found lying around the internet to illustate this:

["Let the Holy Spirit work in their heart to convict them that its sin. That’s His job, not ours. Paul says that “the works of the flesh are evident”"](https://www.whatchristianswanttoknow.com/how-do-i-know-if-something-is-sin-or-not/)

["When we sin the Holy Spirit will make us feel uncomfortable about what we have done (conviction)"](https://www.biblword.net/how-can-i-know-whether-something-is-a-sin/)

This is distinct from having, e.g., read that some particular X is wrong and then feeling bad about it because we have some kind of a posteriori knowledge about the morality of X.  The usual concept of "conscience" doesn't seem to make a distinction - You "feel bad" about something but the mechanism of bad feelings may or may not be a result of, say, morals explicitly learned.

Here's another description that seems relevant:

["To nephew Peter Carr (19 Aug. 1785), Jefferson says that the god-given moral sense, innate and instinctual, is as much a part of a person’s nature as are the senses of hearing and seeing, or as is a leg or arm. Jefferson’s comparisons to hearing and sight invite depiction of the moral sense tied to a bodily organ, like the heart (TJ to Maria Cosway, 12 Oct. 1785)."](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/jefferson/#Mor)

Comment: "When we sin the Holy Spirit will make us feel uncomfortable about what we have done (conviction)" this is obviously false. Plenty of people have committed many a sin, like premarital sex or eat pork, wear mixed fabrics, eat shrimps, work on saturdays and sundays or blasphemy etc and never felt a bit uncomfortable about it. The idea that their exist a sin sense is obviously cultural, if only because each culture has a different notion of sin (if it has this notion at all).

Comment: @armand I know plenty of people who eat shrimp regularly, and it would have never even occurred to them that eating shrimp *could* be right or wrong.  Your argument seems to hinge on the premise that "eating shrimp" is objectively wrong, and that therefore if someone *did* have a "sin sense" they would know not to eat shrimp.  I'm not sure I'm willing to concede that "eating shrimp" is objectively wrong...

Comment: those are examples from the Bible. At least according to this source it is a sin and therefore objectively wrong. What you say just goes into my argument that sin is a social construct and therefore a "sin sense" would be too. If some people consider premarital sex to be a deadly offense and some others have to be told in order to simply entertain the idea that it could be wrong, that shows just how "objective" those views are.

Comment: Your claims about Protestant teachings are not correct. Protestants teach that there are certain moral principles ingrained in human nature, such as loving your children or not murdering, but they also teach that children need to be taught right from wrong in the other things such as not being racist. The action of the Holy Spirit that you allude to is different; it is a miraculous intervention, not an ingrained part of human nature. And finally, Protestants teach that by repeated sinning, people can lose all of their moral senses and no longer be able to distinguish right from wrong.

Comment: @armand, the Bible does not say that eating shell fish is a sin. That is a dietary regulation for the Israelites as part of God's effort to keep them from mingling with other people.

Comment: @DavidGudeman so disobeying God's recommendations is not a sin now ? That's an original take. If we go by this standard the Bible does not consider pedophilia or rape as a sin either (it does, in fact, commend it Numbers 31:17-18) what is more, it changes nothing to the fact that some people take those prescriptions to the letter and consider breaking them to be a sin. So your own different interpretation is allthemore an argument in favor of my point.

Comment: @DavidGudeman to be clear, my question isn't mostly about Christianity or even religion in general.  I'm just using them as an example that is familiar to me, since I live in the west.

Comment: They weren't "recommendations"; they were laws for a specific nation. This is not an original take; it is over 2000 years old. The Bible doesn't commend pedophilia or rape. That passage is allowing for certain people to live instead of being killed: girls too young to spread their culture to the Israelites. The males were killed because leaving a conquered enemy in your lands is begging for disaster in a few generations. This is all old news. I take it you are getting your material from some atheist literature that has never in history bothered to check their straw men with actual Christians.

Comment: @him, that's fine, then please edit your answer to remove the irrelevant (and incorrect) references to Protestant belief so that you don't mislead people. The notion of a moral sense as a sixth sense is well-trod in philosophy and is not specifically connected to Christianity.

Comment: @DavidGudeman what answer?  "The notion of a moral sense as a sixth sense is well-trod in philosophy" - please elaborate on this in an answer!

Comment: if your question i about a 'construct' to a feeling of morality, then the question should be on another stackexchange with possibly psychology or anthropology not on philosophy. If it is about 'sin', then it belongs on christianity stackexchange.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda philosophy has ["constructs"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construct_(philosophy)).  ["sin"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin) is not a concept unique to Christianity, and I did not intend for my question to relate specifically to Christianity - indeed, if anything, my question is about all belief systems *except* Christianity, since the above quotes suggest that Christianity already features such a concept.  Is the concept of a "sin sense" present in other cultures as well?

Comment: According to the stoics such as Zeno of Citium, sin (vice) is simply rooted in the lack or rejection of the construct of universal reason (aka logos), even passive mental states or emotions that are not guided by reason are immoral and produce immoral actions. Thus according to Stoicism, the logos is the construct determining an inherent sense of right or wrong objectively and universally. Since the logos is extremely hidden and hard to be learned without much philosophical effort, most human impulses and desires only rest upon *free* consent, thus sin and suffering is in fact universal...